# How to unmock all modules in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

Although I'm calling `jest.resetModules` before each test, modules mocked in one test are affecting subsequent tests. So I'm having to explicit call `jest.unmock('module')` in the second test. Shouldn't `jest.resetModules` do that already? How can I unmock everything without worrying about what has been mocked before?